# mimicking triggers in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, triggers

I have a question about implementing triggers at hi level, c# .net code; Is that possible at all? I have to develop a browser on exiting database. I need to have some triggers on some of  tables and I cannot,allowed, do this with sql trigger commands? I am using linq for achieveing other functionalities and making connections. However not quite sure if I could benefit from some trigger micking approaches as well here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a confusing question.  Browsers read data.  Triggers respond to writing.  Does your browser write?

Answer (score 0):

Are Events and Delegates what you're after?

Also, when you generate your dbml, it creates partial methods OnXXXChanging() OnXXXChanged() for each field, you could implement something in there to "trigger" an action should a field value change.